# suppress records in main report when subreport has no data

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, crystal-reports-2010

I have looked through the site, but I can't seem to find a method to address this specifically.

I have a main report linked to a sub report.  In cases where the sub report has no data to display I want to suppress the detail for that record in the main report.  In other words, I only want to see records in the main report that have matching data in the sub-report.

It seems the way to do this is to create a shared variable.  I see articles on "counting" the records in the sub report, but I assume what I want to so is assign a Boolean value Yes if it has information, No if it doesn't.  Then suppress the record in the main report if the shared variable is a No.

Any direction on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting thoose rows in another section is not an option?
Then try:

- In the header have the subreport. this subreport should set the shared variable = number of rows. all elements (fields, sections) should be suppressed in this subreport. set the subreport to "suppress blank subreport". set the header section to "suppress blank section".
- In any section after the header - so let's say the footer. put a COPY of the subreport. this subreport will display data if there is data. in the footer section set the "suppress" formula to suppress the footer section if the shared variable from the first subreport returns 0 number of rows.

You need two copies of the subreport. One set to shared variable, the other to display the data. The second must go in a section after the first one. So the first subreport o runs and populate the shared variable. Then you can supress section where the second subreport based on the value of the shared variable.